# How to create a campaign in Netsuite erp

Tags: netsuite

Hi i am working with NetSuite and I just want to know to create a email campaign, what are the required attributes and methods to create a email campaign pro-grammatically?

Any help on this will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nlapiSendCampaignEmail(campaigneventid, recipientid)`

Both, the parameters are required.

As per docs:

> Use this function to send a single “on-demand” campaign email to a
>   specified recipient and return a campaign response ID to track the
>   email. This function works in conjunction with the Lead Nurturing
>   (campaigndrip) sublist only; it does not work with the E-mail
>   (campaignemail) sublist.

Comment: ís their any doc could you please share the link

Comment: click help link when you login to netsuite, and in search type `nlapiSendCampaignEmail` you should be able to find it there